# PHP connection to oracle 11g

Tags: php, oracle11g

I am trying to connect php to oracle 11g and getting below error .
Could not connect to the database. Please check your configuration. error:ErrorException: Use of undefined constant OCI_CRED_EXT - assumed 'OCI_CRED_EXT' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)

Comment: have you look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56105831/use-of-undefined-constant-oci-cred-ext-assumed-oci-cred-ext-laravel

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use of undefined constant OCI\_CRED\_EXT - assumed 'OCI\_CRED\_EXT' laravel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56105831/use-of-undefined-constant-oci-cred-ext-assumed-oci-cred-ext-laravel)